# how to apply format on contact number

Tags: angular, format

I am trying to changing the contact number into specific format in angular 2

```
(mymobile number).format(xxx-xxx-xxxx);
```

but it is not working.
The value inside the format is dynamic.

Comment: Could you please give us more details? Is your `mymobilenumber` part of a `form`? How and where do you get the dynamic format value from?

Comment: mymobile number is value on which i have to format.. and inside the format ,I am passing different format

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipe for this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'contactFormat'
})
export class SortingPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): any {
    // Do your transformation here
  }
}
```

and in your HTML

```
{{mymobile.number | contactFormat}}
```